# Best means to parse TNSNAMES.ORA using awk

Tags: oracle, awk, tnsnames

I have a function I built to parse Tnsnames.ora files. My question is there a better awk statement / query that will give me the results I want.

this is the statement I want to refine so I'll have a shorter code segment: 

 **awk "BEGIN{found=0}/${entry}/{found=1} {if (found) print }")**

I'd like to get rid of the for loop and use AWK to search and find the individual TNSNAME.  Currently I'm counting thru the results of the awk command until I reach the last ) for the passed name.

```
findTnsname()
{
#!/bin/ksh
#inputs:
# $1: stanza title
# $2: Fully qualified input filename
#$3 set to yes will echo how many were found
tnsnames=$(cat $2)
entries=$(echo "$tnsnames"| grep -i "$1.*="| awk '{print $1}')
eNames=$(echo "$entries" | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g')
ecount=$(echo "$entries" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}')
if [ "$3" = "yes" ] ; then
  echo "# found ${ecount} entries -  ${eNames} "
fi
for entry in $entries
{
  #echo "#searching for ${entry}"
  tt=$(echo "$tnsnames" | awk "BEGIN{found=0}/${entry}/{found=1} {if (found) print }")
  t=0     # t for target, means the stanza has been found
  open_parens=0
  close_parens=0
  if [[ -n $tt ]] ; then
    echo "$tt" | while read -r i; do
            if(( t == 1 )); then
                    echo "$i"
                    newline_ck=$(echo "$i" | egrep "^$" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}') 
                    if(( newline_ck > 0 )); then
                            t=0
                            break
                    elif(( open_parens == close_parens && open_parens != 0 )); then
                            t=0

                    else
                            (( open_parens += $(echo "$i" | awk -F"(" '{print NF-1}') ))
                            (( close_parens += $(echo "$i" | awk -F")" '{print NF-1}') ))
                            #echo "# open ${open_parens} close ${close_parens} t ${t}"
                    fi
            else
                    t=$(echo "$i" | egrep -i "^$entry" | wc | awk '{print $1}')
                    if(( t == 1 )); then
                            echo "$i"
                    fi
            fi
    done 
   else
     echo "$entry does not exist in $2"
   fi
 } 
}
```

Results look like this: 
***findTnsname abc "$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora"***

```
ABC_USR.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hosta.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ABC_usr)
)
)

ABCT.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostb.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ABCt)
)
)
```

sample input

```
DEF_USR.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hosta.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = DEF_USR)
)
)

DEFT.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostb.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = DEFT)
)
)

DEF_USR.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostc.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = DEF_USR)
)
)

DEFT.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostd.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = DEFT)
)
)
GHI_USR.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hoste.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = GHI_USR)
)
)

GHIT.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostf.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = GHIT)
)
)
ABC_USR.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hosta.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ABC_usr)
)
)

ABCT.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostb.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ABCt)
)
)
```

Comment: if you just want to find out if a SID or ServiceName is valid, you can use [tnsping](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG378)

Comment: What is the purpose of your script?

Comment: to find TNSNAMES entries in a huge tnsnames file.

Comment: Just being curious: how "huge" is your tnsnames.ora? Mine currently spans 781 lines (opened in my favorite text editor). So, when I'm looking for a specific entry, I press [CTRL+F] which opens a pop-up "find" window, enter search term into a text box and press [ENTER]. I know that you can do that as well, but I don't know why don't you. So - why?

Comment: my TNSNAMES file has 23868 lines.

Comment: You showed us the output you want but not the input you got it from. Post the sample input and the expected output from that input. Also, make sure to tell us which field in the input is the "tnsname" - I can't tell from the output you posted.

Comment: added input example .

Comment: Right but what is your criteria for what to print from that input file? Is it simply any record that starts with ABC or something else? I can see you want to pass `abc` to a script but it's just not clear what you're comparing that `abc` to in the input data to produce the output.

Comment: this line gets all entries that match the passed criteria: entries=$(echo "$tnsnames"| grep -i "$1.*="| awk '{print $1}') then I use those names in a for loop to search in the tnsnames file for a match.

Comment: OK, I don;t know what that means but it's not a good way to do anything. Just tell us - given input of `abc`, which fields do we compare that to in the input to select records for output. Is it the lines like `ABCT.some.company.com =` or the lines like `(SERVICE_NAME = ABCt)` or is it just any part of the record or something else?

Comment: Also - are the input records always separated from each other by blank lines or not? They are not in your example input but idk if that's a typo or not so I'm just making sure.

Comment: If you have so many databases in your premises then you should consider other naming methods, e.g. [Oracle Internet Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/admin.1111/e10029/concepts.htm), aka LDAP name server.

Comment: @EdMorton the input records are linefeed line feed DEFT.some.company.com = linefeed then several ( and several ) want to find between deft - the last )

Comment: That doesn't seem to match the sample input you provided. That sounds like there will be a linefeed between each record but your sample input doesn't always have that. if your sample input doesn't reflect your real input then fix it. Yes, I understand you wanted to print whole records the question is what do you want to match against in each input record to select the records to output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for, depending on the answers to the questions I asked in the comments under your question:

If your input records always have blank lines between them as you suggested in one comment then all you need is:

```
$ awk -v key='abc' -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'tolower($0)~tolower(key)' file
```

otherwise if they sometimes don't as in your provided sample input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
!NF { next }
!/[()]/ { prt(); rec="" }
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
END { prt() }
function prt() {
    if ( tolower(rec) ~ tolower(key) ) {
        print rec
    }
}

$ awk -v key='abc' -f tst.awk file
ABC_USR.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hosta.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ABC_usr)
)
)

ABCT.some.company.com =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostb.some.company.com)(PORT = 1521))
(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = ABCt)
)
)
```

---

EDIT - something else to consider for more control over where to search in which fields and what to print:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=RS; RS=""; ORS="\n" }
{
    delete f

    f["NAME"] = $1
    sub(/[[:space:]]*=.*/,"",f["NAME"])

    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
        n = split($i,tmp,/[ =()]+/)
        for (j=n-2; j>1; j-=2) {
            f[tmp[j]] = tmp[j+1]
        }
    }

    prt()
}

function prt() {
    for (tag in f) {
        print tag "=<" f[tag] ">"
    }
    print "----"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hosta.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<DEF_USR.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<DEF_USR>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hostb.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<DEFT.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<DEFT>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hostc.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<DEF_USR.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<DEF_USR>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hostd.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<DEFT.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<DEFT>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hoste.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<GHI_USR.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<GHI_USR>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hostf.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<GHIT.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<GHIT>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hosta.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<ABC_USR.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<ABC_usr>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
LOAD_BALANCE=<yes>
HOST=<hostb.some.company.com>
PROTOCOL=<TCP>
NAME=<ABCT.some.company.com>
SERVICE_NAME=<ABCt>
SERVER=<DEDICATED>
PORT=<1521>
----
```

Comment: what you provided works nicely. Which is exactly what I was looking for. -thank you

Comment: you gave me what I was looking for the better way to find an item in a file with awk.  I can go from here. - again thank you

Comment: It would be great if you can explain prog file tst.awk briefly. Thank you

Comment: @Chand I think what I'm doing here is fairly straight forward and we can't explain everything about awk in every answer so - is there any particular part of the script that's confusing?